# Validating an email or a phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, email

I have a form field that should accept either an email or a phone number. I already have this code to validate an email address:

```
function validateEmail(email) 
{ 
     var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
     return re.test(email);
}
```

But I also need to validate for a phone number that can only be in this format:

```
+XXX XXX XXX XXX || +XXXXXXXXXXXX || XXX XXX XXX || XXXXXXXXX
```

How do I add that validation, so that I either validate an email or a phone in that format? I'm sorry, I'm a javascript beginner. THANK YOU!

I already have this error message printing done:

```
if(!validateEmail(signup_email))
{
    show_error_msg('error_signup_email','<?php _e( 'Enter a valid email address or a phone number' ); ?>'); 
    jQuery("#signup_email").focus();
    return false;
}
```

---

Progress:
I added a function to validate the phone number:

```
function validatePhone(email)
{
    var re = /^\+?([0-9]{3})\)?[ ]?([0-9]{3})[ ]?([0-9]{3})[ ]?([0-9]{3})$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

And edited the Error message to this:

```
if((!validateEmail(signup_email)) || (!validatePhone(signup_email)))
{
    show_error_msg('error_signup_email','<?php _e( 'Enter a valid email address or a phone number', 'Matrix' ); ?>');   
    jQuery("#signup_email").focus();
    return false;
}
```

But the form stopped printing the success message and it says the phone number is invalid.

Comment: the problem here is I don't really know how to combine these two.. please help

Comment: combine by using `||` or operator

Comment: edited, could you please help?

Comment: You need `&&` not `||` there. You need to check that the entry is both an invalid phone number and an invalid email. Not invalid for either.

Comment: I used AND but still no luck. I'm using a different regex that I know has to work.. but it's still saying it's invalid.

Comment: I really need it fixed today, is there really nobody who could help me with such a trivial task?

Answer (score 1):

How about testing the phone number after you remove the spaces?

```
function validatePhone(phone)
{
    var re = /^(\+\d{3})?\d{9}$/;
    return re.test(phone.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
}
```

This regex is then an optional prefix of a plus symbol and 3 digits followed by 9 digits.

Combining this with some other tweaks, the following has been tested and works.

```
function validateEmail(email) 
{
     var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
     return re.test(email);
}

if(!validateEmail(field) && !validatePhone(field))
{
    show_error_msg('error_signup_email','Enter a valid email address or a phone number');   
    jQuery("#signup_email").focus();
    return false;
}
```

Verification at http://jsfiddle.net/f2rL3pj0/

Answer (score 0):

```
 var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

error expression invalide